# Как передать дескриптор сокета в процесс, созданный с помощью fork, если дескриптор был создан после создания процесса?

Tags: c, unix

Как передать дескриптор сокета в процесс, созданный с помощью fork, если дескриптор был создан после создания процесса?

Comment: Через pipe может?

Comment: Вы комментарии к своим предыдущм (по сути таким же) вопросам читаете?

Comment: @avp, да, щас увидел